# Specialized template for safe copy of char [] with boundary check

Tags: c++, templates

Due to the fact I am working in the project with a library which uses C API I have to use partial `char []` [even I would love to use only `std::string`].

How ever, in order to avoid problems when copying a too long `char *` variable to a *fix-sized* `char []` I was trying to catch this problem with a template.

But unfortunately I am stuck with the specialization. In the project we **can assume** that the *destination* variable is **always** of type `char [fixed-value]` **AND it must not be** `char *`. This is therefore important because there is not really a reliable way to determinate for sure the size of the allocated size of a `char *`.

This is what I tried that far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
void copyWithBoundaryCheck( char destination [], char * source, int maximalSize )
{
    printf( "Correct parameter\n" );
};

template <typename T>
void copyWithBoundaryCheck( T, char * source, int maximalSize )
{
    printf( "Wrong parameter\n" );
};

int main()
{
    char * source = (char *) "Source";
    char * wrongPtr = (char *) malloc( 20 );
    char destination [20];

    copyWithBoundaryCheck( wrongPtr, source, 10 );
    copyWithBoundaryCheck( destination, source, sizeof(destination) );
}
```

This is the output:

```
Wrong parameter <-- output for copyWithBoundaryCheck( wrongPtr, source, 10 );
Wrong parameter <-- output for copyWithBoundaryCheck( destination, source, sizeof(destination) );
```

For `copyWithBoundaryCheck( destination, source, sizeof(destination) );` I was expecting the output `Correct parameter` but I receive always `Wrong parameter`.

**My question:**

How has to be implemented the specialization of the template function `copyWithBoundaryCheck` to *catch* `char [numeric-value]`? According to my example it would mean that `copyWithBoundaryCheck( destination, source, sizeof(destination) );` would display `Correct parameter`.

Comment: any reason you can't use `string::c_str`? or use `vector<char>` for your array?

Comment: You might be looking for `template <size_t N>
void copyWithBoundaryCheck( char (&destination) [N], ...);` I don't quite grasp the purpose of your overloading games. For one thing, the first overload of `copyWithBoundaryCheck` would never be viable in an overload resolution as `T` cannot be deduced.

Comment: This looks a lot like guesswork, which, as so often in C++, does not get you very far. You need to review how arrays work in C++.

Comment: `char [numeric-value]` in a function parameter is just `char*`, so there isn't any size to "catch". You can't really do much with pointers. You need to pass the length (or use a convention such as null-termination.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
template <size_t N>
void copyWithBoundaryCheck(char (&destination)[N])
{
    printf( "Correct parameter of size %zu\n", N );
};
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/TBG41096)

Comment: Yes Sir! Perfect answer! I could test it in the meantime with several types and it is exactly what I was looking for! Upvoted and accepted! Thx a lot! It is now even very elegant because I do **NOT** need to provide the size of the *destination* field. It is resolved by compiler. I love this answer!